# Implement and integrate automated tests with WebdriverIO for multiple microservices

Tags: node.js, selenium, testing, microservices, webdriver-io

Currently we have a separate testautomation framework based on WebdriverIO (NodeJS) which contains different tests for different/multiple (micro)services. Now the goal is to move all the service-oriented tests from the separate framework directly into the service repositories. The problem is now that this will produce a lot of code duplications because we will have the same base testframework implementations in all services.

Do you have experiences with testautomation in a microservice world? How do you share base implementations?

Is there any possibility to create a new node package based on WebdriverIO with all base implementations that could be used in all service repos? And maybe there is also an example existing?

Comment: You can share reusable code as npm package. There is nothing specfic to WebdriverIO here

Comment: @MikeG. yes you are right, but I try to find an entry point to start such a solution. I can create a package with `npm pack` and can install that package in other projects, but then I have my source code inside the node_modules folder. I try to find a quick solution how to make the functionalities such as configs, custom commands etc. directly reusable. Therefore I will need an entry point, such as an index.js or?

Comment: The basic idea is to have reusable and shared test code over multiple service projects with the goal to implement the service oriented tests as fast as possible with the minimum of needed code and configurations. All general stuff should be a part of the own testautomation package. Is there maybe any example project?